# Quickly disable internet browsing on iOS device for parental control

Tags: ios, internet, parental-controls

Whenever I hand the iPad off to one of my kids, I would like to quickly disable or limit internet browsing on the iPad, not necessarily internet altogether, but anything that can be accessed via Safari or an in-app browser.  I know there are the in-built parental restrictions, but modifying the Web restrictions is a six step process to limit sites before, and a six step process to re-enable after.  I would like something that's quicker to use and preferably pin-protected, and something along the lines of "disable for 1 hour" or "disable until I say so".  It doesn't need to be a complete disable of web-browsing, but at the very least, some child-safe mode.

In short, I would like something similar to iOS's own web restrictions, but much quicker to access.

Comment: If what is built-in to iOS is not sufficient, because of the way iOS is set up there is no way to do what you want, even with a third-party app.

Comment: I don't know if this is any quicker, but you could chqnge your DNS servers to Opewn DNS, having first selected your filters - tho they have many preselected sets.

Comment: @tubedogg, with a simple app probably not, but some of this may be possible with a mobile device management/configuration profile, which are sometimes installed via an app.

Comment: Most ISPs have parental controls these days - might be worth investigating how to toggle those on/off; might be quicker